# Ubuntu/Windows XP - Using synergy freezes both PC's

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, freeze, synergy

Using this on Ubuntu:

```
synergyc <IP of the server>
```

and the visual verson on Windows XP. Synergy works fine for about 30-60 minutes but then it freezes BOTH computers - I end up with no control over anything, even the Windows XP server.

It takes 10 minutes or so for me to be able to get a cursor on my server.

I cant use the visual Synergy on Ubuntu, only the command line seems to be working.

- Why might this freezing be happening?
- Are there any ways to stop the freezing?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define 'freezing' - can you still use the client's mouse and keyboard while this is happening?  Since you are running a Windows server, can you press Alt+Ctrl+Del to cause an action on the server while it is frozen?  Either of these two actions means the machines are not actually frozen, but there is some problem with Synergy.

If on the other hand neither of these two actions are possible then your problem lies elsewhere, as it is not possible for Synergy to fully lock up a computer in this manner.  It may be doing something that triggers a bug elsewhere (e.g. network or video card drivers) which then results in a lockup, but in that case the bug is external to Synergy.

Comment: If I pres control-alt-del (winxp), &/or move the curser - things move about 10+ minutes after i did the action (basically i can't see what is happening. Curser dissapears too from either/both machines, So I cant see it.

Comment: @Sarah: It sounds like the problem could be swapping.  If you have a program continually chewing up memory then after an hour there may be no memory left, so the hard drive will be working like crazy and everything will become incredibly slow.  Perhaps you could keep an eye on the Processes tab in Task Manager, and see if anything is using up excessive amounts of memory?

Comment: I found out that Gmail with Google Chrome eats up a lot of memory - I'm using Gmail on the other (client) PC now  & my memory on my server isn't being chewed up as much. (though I have some tabs open in Chrome)